# For SSIS Tutorial, the difference between deploying to the Integration Services Catalogs and the Integration Services Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have gone through the Microsoft SSIS tutorial for [Create a Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-6-4-deploying-the-lesson-6-package) and [Deploy Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-3-3-testing-the-deployed-packages). For the first, I converted to a project deployment model, and then deploy through the SSISDB Catalog. For the second, I had to transfer the deployment bundle to the target server to install it and then log in to the Integration Services Server to run it. It seems that the first is [the current project deployment model and the second is the legacy package deployment model] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages) if I am correct.

My question is when would you choose the second option? What is the Integration Services Server use for? When I deploy through the SSISDB Catalog in the first option, why is my package not in the Integration Services Server's Stored Packages folder? This is also vise-versa.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to give you answers point by point to the best of my understanding:

*My question is when would you choose the second option? What is the Integration Services Server use for?*

- Legacy package deployment model, as the name says is a legacy. It was used before SQL Server 2012. It is still existing in 2012+ in order to support the existing projects of clients and customers.
- Integration Services Server is used only for package deployment model and not project deployment model(answer of your second question).

*When I deploy through the SSISDB Catalog in the first option, why is my package not in the Integration Services Server's Stored Packages folder? This is also vise-versa.*

- As stated above, Integration Services Server is used only for package deployment model and not project deployment model.
- Basically, Project deployment model stored the SSIS project(and package) in `Integration Services Catalogs > SSISDB` whereas Package deployment model stores the packages in `Integration Services Server > Stored Packages > File System`

you can read about differences in detail from [microsoft technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290(v=sql.110).aspx) , [microsoft msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/678bd05c-4475-45af-ad25-51e8700dbe21/where-is-ssis-package-stored?forum=sqlintegrationservices) and [microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/legacy-package-deployment-ssis)